# Is there a word for a person who takes well care of his/her belongings?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are people who keep their things in a prim and proper manner. They take good care of their stuff and use it with care.

Is there a single word to describe them?

Comment: `anal-retentive` :)

Comment: A good steward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *[neat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neat#Adjective)* meshes well with adjectives *prim* and *proper* mentioned in the question.  From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neat#Adjective), *neat* has a sense, among others, of “Having a simple elegance or style; clean, trim, tidy, tasteful”.

Also consider *fastidious* and  *persnickety*.   From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fastidious#Adjective), *fastidious* means “Excessively particular, demanding, or fussy about details, especially about tidiness and cleanliness”.  Also from [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/persnickety#Adjective), *persnickety* means “Fastidious or fussy”.

Answer (score 2):

Such a person would be ***organized***.

From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/organized):

> 1.1 **Able to plan one’s activities efficiently:**
>   *she used to be so organized*
>
> Examples-
>
> - I worked for a guy who said that he loved employing pregnant women because they were so organized and efficient.
> - This is my major preoccupation at the moment: forgiving myself for not being efficient and organised and sensible.
> - After one and one-half years in her current position, she finds that she has learned to be more organized and efficient with her time,
>     which gives her more time with the patient.

Organized is a very broad term, and can be used to indicate a person who is adept in managing several things- be it things/belongings, time, life etc.

Answer (score 1):

Words that came to my mind:

- Organised
- efficient
- precise
- fastidious
- methodical
- thorough

Answer (score 0):

Steward?

1 a person who looks after the passengers on a ship, aircraft, or train and brings them meals.
• a person responsible for supplies of food to a college, club, or other institution.
2 an official appointed to supervise arrangements or keep order at a large public event, for example a sporting event.
• short for shop steward.
3 a person employed to manage another's property, esp. a large house or estate.
• a person whose responsibility it is to take care of something: farmers pride themselves on being stewards of the countryside.

Comment: You should cite where you retrieved your definitions from -- eg. which dictionary -- and maybe include a sentence or two as an example of how to use the word in an appropriate fashion.

Answer (score -1):

Fastidious
Curatorial
Conservationist